# Most pythonic way to batch load and process images

Tags: python

The code below loads jpeg images into an array of numpy ndarrays. Currently it works fine, but I feel like there must be a more pythonic way of doing this.

```
import scipy.ndimage as spimg
import numpy as np


# Read images into scipy and flatten to greyscale
# Using generator function instead of list comprehension
# for memory efficiency
human_files_convert = (spimg.imread(path, flatten=True) for path in human_files[:2099])
```

Using a generator function above so that each image is processed individually, a list comprehension here fails.

```
batch_size = 1000
step = 0
human_files_ndarray = np.empty((1, 250, 250))

# Create empty list, to append empty image arrays
human_files_list = []
batch = 1
total_processed = 0

# iterate through image arrays
for path in human_files_convert:
    # Append to list
    human_files_list.append(path)
    # Stack list of arrays
    step += 1
    total_processed += 1
    if (step % batch_size == 0) or (len(human_files[:2099]) == total_processed):
        new_stack = np.stack(human_files_list)
        print("Batch: ", batch)
        print(new_stack.shape)
        step = 0
        human_files_ndarray = np.concatenate((human_files_ndarray, new_stack))
        print(human_files_ndarray.shape)
        print(total_processed)
        # Create empty list, to append empty image arrays
        human_files_list = []
        batch += 1
```

Any ideas on how to make this code more efficient or pythonic?

Comment: What exactly are you doing there? What's the idea? The shape of (x,250,250) looks like you just want ```imgs = np.stack(human_files_convert)```? What kind of memory-shortage you have (you will have a dense output-array after all)? If there is, do you really want to load them all into memory (opposed to HDF5 or such)?

Comment: I am trying to stack all of the image files to one array. Much like you just mentioned. But I am trying to batch the conversion due to memory constraints. I will definitely give you idea a try.

Comment: That worked like a charm. I knew I was hitting that with the nuclear-sledgehammer. If you'll put that answer in, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid i don't feel good with putting it as an answer. It's good it's working for you now. I was under the assumption, that there are some limited scenarios where batch-wise processing helps. Simplified guess: if adding one image after another memory-usage should be ```x + eps```, while adding all at once should be at most ```x*2```. Now this seems only relevant if you within this special memory-constraints, e.g. your final array occupies somewhat like 80% of your memory.

Comment: @sascha my final array does occupy approx 80%-90% of my memory, and that is only a portion of my total dataset. I will take a look at the topics you mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the suggestion of @sascha above, I sent the output of my generator function to an [hdf5](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/) file. Doing this took memory usage from > 4GB for the set to less than 200MB. Added bonus is I now have a disk copy of the loaded dataset, much like a pickle file.

```
# Confirm correct import of images
import scipy.ndimage as spimg
import numpy as np
import h5py
import tqdm

np.set_printoptions(threshold=1000)

# Use h5py to store large uncompressed image arrays
img = h5py.File("images.hdf5", "w")
human_dset = img.create_dataset("human_images", (len(human_files), 250, 250))

# Read images into scipy and flatten to greyscale
# Using generator function instead of list comprehension
# for memory efficiency
slice = len(human_files)
human_files_convert = (spimg.imread(path, flatten=True) for path in human_files[:slice])

i = 0
for r in tqdm.tqdm(human_files_convert, total=slice):
    # Rescale [0,255] --> [0,1]
    r = r.astype('float32')/255
    # Insert Row into dset
    human_dset[i] = r
    i += 1
img.close()
```