# Out of memory converting image files to numpy array

Tags: python, image, numpy, imread

I'm trying to run a loop that iterates through an image folder and returns two numpy arrays: **x** - stores the image as a numpy array **y** - stores the label.

A folder can easily have over 40.000 rgb images, with dimensions (224,224).
I have around 12Gb of memory but after some iterations, the used memory just spikes up and everything stops.

What can I do to fix this issue?

```
def create_set(path, quality):
    x_file = glob.glob(path + '*')
    x = []

    for i, img in enumerate(x_file):
        image = cv2.imread(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        x.append(np.asarray(image))
        if i % 50 == 0:
            print('{} - {} images processed'.format(path, i))

    x = np.asarray(x)
    x = x/255

    y = np.zeros((x.shape[0], 2))
    if quality == 0:
        y[:,0] = 1
    else:
        y[:,1] = 1 

    return x, y
```

Comment: Change your algorithm or buy more memory... Unfortunately your computer has only limited memory (you say 12 Gb) a part of which is used by the OS, a part for the Python interpretor and the used libraries, and convertions costs some overhead. Do you really need to process all images in memory at the same time?

Comment: I just learned the hard way that loading all of them in memory is definitely not the way. I don't need them to be processed at the same time, I just need them processed into a numpy array.

Comment: Then process them one at a time, and close all resources between processing the next one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just can't load that many images into memory. You're trying to load every **file** in a given path to memory, by appending them to x.

Try processing them in batches, or if you're doing this for a tensorflow application try writing them to .tfrecords first.

If you want to save some memory, leave the images as np.uint8 rather than casting them to float (which happens automatically when you normalise them in this line > `x = x/255`)

You also don't need `np.asarray` in your `x.append(np.asarray(image))` line. `image` is already an array. `np.asarray` is for converting lists, tuples, etc to arrays.

**edit:**

a very rough batching example:

```
def batching function(imlist, batchsize):
    ims = []
    batch = imlist[:batchsize]

    for image in batch:
        ims.append(image)
        other_processing()

    new_imlist = imlist[batchsize:]
    return x, new_imlist

def main():
    imlist = all_the_globbing_here()
    for i in range(total_files/batch_size):
        ims, imlist = batching_function(imlist, batchsize)
        process_images(ims)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Regarding the processing in batches, how'd you do it? I've never done anything like it, got any examples or anything I could read?

Comment: It depends on your application. The most simple way is to set a batch size and do your processing in a for loop.

Comment: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48449391/most-pythonic-way-to-batch-load-and-process-images) a [couple](http://www.coderholic.com/batch-image-processing-with-python/)

Comment: I added an edit with a pseudo-codey example. Hope that helps.