# How to decrease the RAM usage when converting images to numpy array?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to convert a large RGB image data set with 3618 and 480x480 size to numpy array, but the operation stops for RAM issue.

I tried many solution, but none of them worked.

here is the code I tried :

```
   def batching_function(imlist, batchsize):
       ims = []
       if batchsize < len(imlist):
         batch = imlist[:batchsize]
       elif batchsize == len(imlist):
         batch = imlist[:batchsize-1]
       else:
         batch = imlist[:len(imlist)-1]

       ims = np.array(batch,dtype='float32')
       new_imlist = imlist[batchsize:]
       return ims, new_imlist



   imlist = dataset # list of arrays of images : size = 3617 , dataset[1].shape = (480, 480, 3)
   batchsize = 100
   total_files =  3618
   ims0 = np.empty((0,480, 480, 3))
   for i in range(int(total_files/batchsize)+1):    
           imsnew, imlist = batching_function(imlist, batchsize)
           ims0 = np.concatenate((ims0, imsnew))
```

Comment: Can you add the error ?

Comment: why do you use this batching function instead of just imlist[i, i+batchsize]

Comment: I am using google colab and it didn't display an error only a message that the RAM usage is off limits and the environment was restarted.

Comment: I used it as a solution for the ram,please refer to this Answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50721762/out-of-memory-converting-image-files-to-numpy-array

Answer (score 0):

Function `numpy.savez_compressed` can get as first argument bufor instead of file path. Same with `numpy.load`. So you can compress part of images for temporary reduce size of images.

But if will cost you additional calculation time.

`numpy.ndarray` store data in uncopresed form to speedup access. And cannot reduce RAM usage without losing information (like convert to `numpy.float16`)