# failed to convert image to array on google colab

Tags: python, numpy

I need help. I am using google colab to train a CNN  model. I have 9101 images in my train_set but got a problem when I try to convert the image to array for my training set.

Here are my code:

```py
def convert_image_to_array(files):
    array_img = []
    for file in files:
        array_img.append(img_to_array(load_img(file)))
    return np.array(array_img)
X_train = convert_image_to_array(X_train)
print(X_train.shape)
```

It always failed to convert the images and the google collab keep restarting due to crashed after using all available RAM.
The same code worked well with the test_set that the size are only 2277 images.

Can anybody please help me solve this problem? So it works well on google collab?

Thank you

Comment: If you have an error, please add it to your question

Comment: Thank you, J'e, but no, it is not an error, Its just the google colab keep crushing and restarting so it fails to convert the image into array.

Comment: I think the problem here might be you are trying to append the entire dataset into the list. Even though this should not happen and I am assuming the dataset is larger than the resources available to you.

Comment: Thanks @AnuragReddy. Yes, I think so. Is there any other way to convert the images?

Comment: I think processing them in batches might help then. Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50721762/out-of-memory-converting-image-files-to-numpy-array). This might help you. Also, probably use a pytorch or keras dataloader in this case.

Comment: All right, thank you @AnuragReddy